# python gnupg not encrypting file

Tags: python, gnupg

I am trying to encrypt a file with a GPG key but the output is keeps being empty:

```
>>> import gnupg
>>> home_dir = '~/.gnupg'
>>> pgp = gnupg.GPG(gnupghome=home_dir)
>>> key = open('ff.asc', 'rb')
>>> fp = open('test.txt', 'rb')
>>> res = pgp.import_keys(key.read())
>>> res.results
[{'fingerprint': 'C3...', 'text': 'Not actually changed\n', 'ok': '0'}]
>>> enc = pgp.encrypt_file(fp, 'C3...')
>>> enc.data
b''
```

What am I missing here?

Also, is it possible to pass the public GPG key directly to the encryption function from a string without having to import it?

Comment: Can you try putting the recipient key ID (or fingerprint) in a list in the call to `encrypt_file`?

Comment: Tried it now, but didn't help...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem may be that the imported key is not trusted. From the [documentation of gnupg](http://pythonhosted.org/python-gnupg/#encryption):

> **Note:**
>
> Any public key provided for encryption should be trusted, otherwise
>   encryption fails but without any warning. This is because gpg just
>   prints a message to the console, but does not provide a specific error
>   indication that the Python wrapper can use.

The simplest solution is to use the `always_trust` keyword argument of encryption functions:

> `always_trust` (defaults to **`False`**) - Skip key validation and
>   assume that used keys are always fully trusted.

Thus your encryption statement should read

```
enc = pgp.encrypt_file(fp, 'C3...', always_trust=True)
```